# C# command that lets you runs once when the app first starts and never again

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in unity that requires to generate a user ID once. Is there any way to have a function that only run once and never again? I wanted to generate a random user ID, and save it on the android device, and load the ID back when the app starts again without it generating a new ID again. Please advice thank you all :)

Comment: Can't the function be Start()?

Comment: Do you prefere a random Id, or a value calculated as a "fingerprint" of the device? The fingerprint has the advantages 1) you don't need to save it, you can calculate it every time; 2) after an uninstall and new install of your game you get the same Id.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to generate it a start and then load it from some sort of file you can set it default to null so you can make something like this:

```
void Start()
{
    int id=ReadID()//function that reads the id saved
    if(id==null)//id has not been set
    { 
          GenerateId()//some function that generates id
    }
}
```

so you can make the id null by default and set it here

Comment: This is the question, not a solution.